# How to set Swift flags for local packages in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, compile-time

I'm trying to figure out how long does the Swift compiler take to build my app every time and reduce time on type checks and functions where possible. I found many articles on the internet, explaining how to add these "Other Swift Flags" in the Build Settings of the Target to get Build Time warnings in Xcode.

```
-Xfrontend -warn-long-expression-type-checking=100
-Xfrontend -warn-long-function-bodies=100
```

One such article [here](https://www.onswiftwings.com/posts/build-time-optimization-part1/), for context.

[image: Article explaining how to set Swift flags]

The problem is that Xcode shows warnings about files only in the main app. I have a number of local Swift packages in the project and I can't find a way to do the same checks on the code inside those packages.

I tried adding these Swift Flags to the Project and the Target in Xcode, but it is of no use. I can't find anywhere to specify such flags for Swift Packages.

Comment: Check [this](https://forums.swift.org/t/compiler-flags-in-package-swift/11668/2) thread.